# hr list item underline align with section shown in view when scrolling

Tags: jquery, css

I have built an funny thing, but now little stuck. My issue is that the `<hr>` underline should follow the section as well, meaning that if the visitor is scrolling to for instance section skills, the `<hr>` should underline list item "skills".  Now if I scroll down the page, the `<hr>` still stays stick to the first list item.

```js
$("ul").find("li").click(function(e) {  
 e.preventDefault(); //prevent from triggering this event
 var scrollTo = $(this).attr("href"); 
 $(this).removeClass("current");
 $(this).parent("li").addClass("current");
 $("html, body").animate({
  scrollTop: $(scrollTo).offset().top
 }, 5000, "linear");
});
```

```css
#nav-block {
 width: 750px;
 float: right;
 margin-top: 22px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#navbar-unordered-list li {
 display: inline;
 text-align: center;
}

.navbar-list-items {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 120px;
 padding: .75rem 0;
 margin: 0;
 color: red;
}

.navbar-list-items:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}

.one.current ~ hr,
#navbar-unordered-list li.one:hover ~ hr {
 margin-left: 0;
}

.two.current ~ hr,
#navbar-unordered-list li.two:hover ~ hr {
 margin-left: 120px;
}

.three.current ~ hr,
#navbar-unordered-list li.three:hover ~ hr {
 margin-left: 240px;
}

.four.current ~ hr,
#navbar-unordered-list li.four:hover ~ hr {
 margin-left: 360px;
}

.five.current ~ hr,
#navbar-unordered-list li.five:hover ~ hr {
 margin-left: 480px;
}

hr {
 padding: 2px;
 width: 120px;
 margin: 0;
 height: 2px;
 background: tomato;
 border: none;
 transition: .8s ease-in-out;
}

.sections {
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 min-height: 20px;
 padding: 40px;
 width: 100%;
}

#sectionOne, 
#sectionThree, 
#sectionFive {
 background-color: #2196F3;
 color: white;
}

#sectionTwo, 
#sectionFour,
#sectionSix {
 background-color: #e7e9ec;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="nav-block">
    <ul id="navbar-unordered-list">
      <li class="one"><a href="#sectionOne" class="navbar-list-items">Profile</a></li>
      <li class="two"><a href="#sectionTwo" class="navbar-list-items">Personal Project</a></li>
      <li class="three"><a href="#sectionThree" class="navbar-list-items">Skills</a></li>
      <li class="four"><a href="#sectionFour" class="navbar-list-items">CSS drawings</a></li>
      <li class="five"><a href="#sectionFive" class="navbar-list-items">Contact</a></li>
      <hr>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
    <section class="sections" id="sectionOne">
      <p>Profile</p>
     </section>
  
      <section class="sections" id="sectionTwo">
      <p>Personal Project</p>
     </section>
  
      <section class="sections" id="sectionThree">
      <p>Skills</p>
     </section>
  
      <section class="sections" id="sectionFour">
      <p>CSS drawings</p>
     </section>
  
      <section class="sections" id="sectionFive">
      <p>Contact</p>
     </section>
  </body>
```

Comment: WHat does *"follow it"* mean? Question is unclear as is expected behavior

Comment: Sorry, the navbar  should have positioned fixed. If you checkout the code snippet, you likely will understand now what I exactly mean. The <hr> should underline the current list item when someone during scrolling.

Comment: Not really. You haven't clearly identified what is or isn't working ... in clear and specific terms. Comment mentions navbar but question is about `<hr>`. Confusing

Comment: Have edited again, hopefully you understand my point now.

Comment: For starters, `<hr>` is invalid child of `<ul>` and problem is still vague. Take some time to read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
(function(){
    $("ul").find("li").click(function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent from triggering this event
        var scrollTo = $(this).find('a').attr("href"); 
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $(scrollTo).offset().top
        }, 2000, "linear");
    });
})();
```

working example  [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wgqbkwft/)

Comment: Does not work well unfortunately. Checkout my code snippet, have just edited.

Answer (score 0):

I edited javascript/jquery part only, with few fixes. Here is one solution, where `<hr>` element follows window offset top property. You will notice that it is not aligned to sections.

```
 var initialHrTop;
$(document).ready(function(){


    $("ul").find("li").click(function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent from triggering this event
    var scrollTo = $(this).find('a').attr("href");  // fixed this, added .find('a')
    window.location.hash = scrollTo; // to change hash in browser url input  
    $(this).removeClass("current");
    $(this).parent("li").addClass("current");
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(scrollTo).offset().top
    }, 1000, "linear"); //shorten time for image  
});
$('hr').css('position','absolute');
initialHrTop = parseInt($('hr').offset().top);
 $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = parseInt($(window).scrollTop());
    // Do something
    var hrTop = parseInt($('.section-line').offset().top);


        $('hr').css('left' ,'0px');
        $('hr').css('top' , scroll + initialHrTop + 'px');

    if(scroll == 0){
        $('hr').css('left' ,'');
    }
}); 


});
```

Second solution is done, so `hr` element follows the offset position of each section:

```
var initialHrTop;
$(document).ready(function(){


    $("ul").find("li").click(function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent from triggering this event
    var scrollTo = $(this).find('a').attr("href");  // fixed this, added .find('a')
    window.location.hash = scrollTo; // to change hash in browser url input  
    $(this).removeClass("current");
    $(this).parent("li").addClass("current");
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(scrollTo).offset().top
    }, 1000, "linear"); //shorten time for image  
});
$('hr').css('position','absolute');
initialHrTop = parseInt($('hr').offset().top);


$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    //var scroll = parseInt($(window).scrollTop());

    var hrTop = parseInt($('.section-line').offset().top);
    var currentSection = window.location.hash;
    if(currentSection != ''){
    var currentSectionPosition =$(currentSection).offset().top;
    var currentSectionHeight = $(currentSection).height();
    $('hr').css('left' ,'0px');
    $('hr').css('top' , currentSectionPosition + initialHrTop + 'px');
    }



    if(scroll == 0){
        $('hr').css('left' ,'');
    }
});
});
```

This is just a touch of solution, in which direction you should go, the rest of stuff depends on what is your primary goal on this :).

Also, you will notice that I added window.location.hash change, on menu item click event, this is essential for second solution, letting us know to which section `hr` element should refer to.

Comment: Think the second hr part is what I need